# How come span accept padding-top and padding-bottom?

Tags: html, css, padding, margin

As i was reading all over the internet span element is inline element and does not accept vertical padding and i was like let me try it and let see. So i opened the editor and try to add vertical padding and somehow it worked.

Here is my HTML and CSS code:

```css
span {
  background-color:blue;
  padding-left:5rem;
  padding-bottom:5rem;
  padding-top:4rem;    
}
```

```html
<span>
  asdfasdfsadfl
</span>
```

I will also add the ss of it:

[image]

Could you please explain me what am I missing here?

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ? Have a `display: inline-block` on the span ?

Answer (score 1):

Main purpose of using inline element is to have parts arranged in a line and not as a separate section.Even if you include padding in span tag it won't push the text
to create padding but will expand itself in outward direction without disturbing the text flow.Below is the code to prove the same

```css
span{
    background-color:blue;
    padding-top: 100px;
    padding-bottom:100px; 
    margin-top: 50px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    }
```

```html
<p id="p" style="padding: 20px; border: 2px solid black;">block-block<span id="n">&nbsp-INLINE-&nbsp</span>block-block-block-block-block-block-block-block-block-block-block-block-block-block-block-block-block-block-block-block-block-block-block-block-block-block-block-block-block-block-block-block-block-block-block-block-block-block-block-blockblock-block-block-block-block-block-block-block-block-block-block-block-block-block</p>
```